# ANDROID : App retrieves wrong directory / file path

Tags: android

I created an app that enables the user to capture an image then displays it in ImageView.

then I have a button that saves the image to the database by retrieving the image by getting the file path / directory.

but unfortunately it retrieves wrong directory which is this : `/data/user/0/com.crem.eloan/cache/1609139672287.jpg`

then I checked the image using file manager the image is in here : `/data/user/0/com.crem.eloan/cache/camera/1609139672287.jpg`

check out this code

```
uriApp = data.getParcelableExtra("path");
try {
    // You can update this bitmap to your server
    bitmapApp = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getActivity().getContentResolver(), uriApp);
    // loading profile image from local cache
    pictureFilePath = uriApp.getPath();
    Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: "+pictureFilePath);

    //loadProfile(uriApp.toString());
    imgProfile.setImageBitmap(bitmapApp);
 } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Image Capture Code:

```
private void takeCameraImage() {
    Dexter.withActivity(this)
            .withPermissions(Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            .withListener(new MultiplePermissionsListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPermissionsChecked(MultiplePermissionsReport report) {
                    if (report.areAllPermissionsGranted()) {
                        fileName = System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";
                        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, getCacheImagePath(fileName));
                        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(List<PermissionRequest> permissions, PermissionToken token) {
                    token.continuePermissionRequest();
                }
            }).check();
}
```

getCacheImagePath code:

```
private Uri getCacheImagePath(String fileName) {
    File path = new File(getExternalCacheDir(), "camera");
    if (!path.exists()) path.mkdirs();
    File image = new File(path, fileName);
    return getUriForFile(ImagePickerActivity.this, getPackageName() + ".provider", image);
}
```

Comment: How you are making directory?

Comment: @NadimAnsari by capturing an image using camera

Comment: Can You share the code of making directory?

Comment: @NadimAnsari check the code above

Comment: Can you add the code of onActivityResult()?

Comment: `getCacheImagePath(fileName))` ? Well .... If you complain about a path... Then where is the code?

Comment: @blackapps I added the code above

Comment: Ok. But what path is it that that function delivers?

Comment: `/data/user/0` is a path unaccessable for a normal file manager app. Please explain.

Comment: Thankyou everyone for your feed back. I managed to do a workaround and satisfied with the output also @blackapps you are right that `/data/user/0` is a path unaccessable for a normal file manager app that's why I realized to do this `pictureFilePath= pictureFilePath.replace("/data/user/0/info.androidhive.navigationdrawer/cache/","/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/info.androidhive.navigationdrawer/cache/camera");`